# A problem with function and for-loop for calculating average

Tags: javascript

What's the problem with my javascript code?
This is a practice of simple app that gets numbers and calculate average and show it.

```
var dataArr = [];

function addD() {
  var dataSin = prompt("What number do you want to add?");
  dataArr[dataArr.length] = dataSin;
  document.getElementById("targetD").innerHTML = dataArr;
}

function getR() {
  var sum =0;

  for(i=0; i<dataArr.length; i++) {

    var sum = sum += dataArr[i];
  }

  document.getElementById("targetR").innerHTML = sum/dataArr.length;
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem in your code.

Comment: Don't redefine the variable sum, remove the `var` keyword in the loop

Comment: `var sum = sum += dataArr[i];` this doesn't makes sense to me, you probably want `sum+= dataArr[i]`

Comment: Who is calling `getR` and `addD`

Comment: Btw, instead of `dataArr[dataArr.length] = dataSin;`, use `dataArr.push(dataSin)`.

Comment: This app doesn't get any numbers, it gets strings. And `anything + string` is a string concatenation in JS.

Comment: That sum variable redefine is a mistake. in my code that doesn't appear.

Comment: The problem is "when I run getR function the output is strange number instead of average. For example I add 20 and 10 as inputs, output become 1005 instead of 15.

Comment: 1005 is half of 2010, the concatenation of "20" and "10". You need to parse dataSin as a number as mentioned by @Thomas

Comment: Thomas you mean that "prompt" only can get strings? But if they were strings, the function couldn't produce a final number. I get a final number but with two extra 0 number. For example 1005 instead of 15.

Comment: How could I perform this? @samthecodingman

Comment: There is no difference between these two statements. @QuentinVeron

Comment: Yes there is @MiladSharifiTehrani . Both will work but one is the correct way to proceed.

Comment: Finally, it worked with "parseInt". Why prompt doesn't automatically recognize numbers? There is still a small problem: prompt gets a number but ignore its decimal. For example, I type 19.5 in prompt but it returns 19. @Thomas

Comment: Now it completely works. The solution was "parseFloat". Thank you all for your support, hints and helps. @Thomas

Comment: @MiladSharifiTehrani *"Why prompt doesn't automatically recognize numbers?"* How about "numbers" with leading or trailing zeroes? What about something as simple as `101`? Do you mean the decimal `101` or the binary `5` or the hexadecimal `257` or maybe even the octal `65`? Or it was just a reference to the movie "Ready player one"? Think what would happen if `prompt` would start "interpreting" with your inputs. Like, are you lucky and it gets it right what you meant? This time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to calculate average value check out code below. It using more functional way which works good with JS.

```js
const getSum = (numbers) => numbers.reduce((sum, n) => sum + n, 0)

const getAverage = (numbers) => getSum(numbers) / numbers.length

const avgHasToBe3 = [ 3, 6, 2, 3, 1 ]
console.log(getAverage(avgHasToBe3))
```

If you want to stick with `for` approach, make small to changes to your code like so.

```
function getR() {
  var sum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i++) {
    sum += dataArr[i];
  }

  document.getElementById("targetR").innerHTML = sum / dataArr.length;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I want to practice for-loop so I must declare a for-loop for calculating average.

Comment: @MiladSharifiTehrani Added `for` approach to my answer.

Comment: @MiladSharifiTehrani Glad to help. Also don't forget to mark answer as correct if it solves your problem)